# Linq Expressions: The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'MyEnum' and 'System.Enum'

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-expressions

I convert some of data from a WinGrid to an expression, in order to filter some output to the user. 
I have an initial collection (of MyObjectType), I apply some dynamic filters, and I obtain a filtered collection.

I have problems however with an enumeration - property of MyObjectType.

the enumeration is a standard enumeration

```
Public Enum MyEnum
  A
  B 
  C
End Enum
```

this is how I obtain the expression:

```
Dim constantExpression As ConstantExpression
If TypeOf Value Is [Enum] Then
  constantExpression = Expression.Constant(Value, GetType([Enum]))
Else
  constantExpression = Expression.Constant(Value, Value.GetType())
End If
...
Dim expr As Expression = Nothing
Dim objectPropertyParam = Expression.Property(objectParam, objectPropertyName)

Select Case Me.Operation
  Case ComparisonOperator.Contains, ComparisonOperator.NotContains
  ...
  Case ComparisonOperator.NotEqual
  ...

  Case ComparisonOperator.Equal
    ' THE EXCEPTION IS HERE ---------------------------------------
    expr = Expression.Equal(objectPropertyParam, constantExpression)

  Case ComparisonOperator.GreatherThanOrEqual
    expr = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(objectPropertyParam, constantExpression)
  Case ComparisonOperator.LessThanOrEqual
    expr = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(objectPropertyParam, constantExpression)
End Select
```

then the following exception occurs:

> The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'MyEnum' and
>   'System.Enum'.
>
> at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetEqualityComparisonOperator(ExpressionType
>   binaryType, String opName, Expression left, Expression right, Boolean
>   liftToNull)    at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Equal(Expression
>   left, Expression right)

[image]

## PS.

I observed that if I do

```
expr = Expression.Equal(objectPropertyParam, 
       Expression.Convert(constantExpression, GetType(MyEnum)))
```

**This Works**, but I'd would like do not specity each type of enumerations like this, because is a generic function!?

Comment: Can't you use the `Is` operator?

Comment: `Is`?! is not used with expressions, but between objects

Comment: Sorry, it's actually not clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Agreed.  It's not clear what you are trying to do.  Also, where do `Value`, `objectParam` and `objectPropertyName` come from?  Also, as an aside, VB is not C# - there is no case sensitivity so `Dim constantExpression As ConstantExpression` is a no-no.  It works, but you hide `ConstantExpression` for the remainder of the context.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `If TypeOf Value Is [Enum]` condition? I think that's what's causing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is the difference between `Object.Equals` and `MyEnum.Equals`.  Instead of using `Expression.Equal` use `Expression.Call` to call the constant's `Equals` method.

Alternatively, if this is always done with enums then you can convert them all to integers safely (or whatever the largest backing type is).  Then you don't have to hard-code converting to a specific enum--it will work with any integer-based enum.  If it's used for things besides enums, then using `Expression.Call` is best.